# What airplane needs the longest runway to land?

Tags: landing

What airplane (excluding spaceplanes) requires the longest runway for a safe landing?

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  Are you wanting to compare runway length for different aircraft under identical conditions or are you interested in the longest specified length in worst-case conditions.  And is this specified min runway length or actual distance-to-stop?

Comment: FWIW most aircraft need a longer runway for takeoff than for landing (since they are heavier during takeoff)

Comment: I am guessing that you mean at maximum landing weight, maybe you can clarify just to be sure.

Comment: @Frog - It seems pretty safe to assume that they are referring to identical conditions as other comparisons would be meaningless. I would also think that it's probably for normal conditions (dry runway, 0 wind etc) but I agree that could use some clarification. It may be difficult or nearly impossible to come up with a definitive maximum, but I for one would be interested to know what are some of the typical landing distances in normal conditions for various types of airliners, cargo planes, military fighter jets, etc.

Comment: From experience with the F-84F: "If someone builds a runway all the way around the earth, Republic will build an airplane that needs every inch of it!"

Comment: Under what conditions? Landing distances are all dependent upon the airframe, landing weight, aircraft landing configuration, obstacle clearance at the runway approach end, approach speed, ambient atmospheric conditions, wind direction, field elevation and runway slope and conditions. You would have to set up some criteria here and make an evaluation based on this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably some really large and heavy aircraft, hence [Antonov An-225 Mriya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-225_Mriya) looks like a best candidate (there are currently no flying aircraft remaining but there are intentions to build more). It needs about 3500 m and possibly more.

Comment: Interesting.  Where is the data pointing to a landing runway length of 3500m?